# Symfony2 duplicates collection entities when form index is missing

Tags: php, forms, entity-framework, symfony

I am using Symfony 2 and its form component to manage some relations.

```
$builder->add('locations', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new LocationType(), 
    'options' => array("em" => $this->em), 
    "allow_add" => true, 
    "by_reference" => false, 
    "allow_delete" => true, 
    "delete_empty" => true
));
```

I use a many 2 many relation with extra fields, so I use many-to-one and one-to-many

It works like I want. New entities can be created. To delete entities, I provide an AJAX function which removes the item from the DB and deletes the corresponding HTML part of the form.

When I have 2 entities in the collection, delete the first one and do not reload the form, the form has one entity element left. But this one has the index 1 and not 0. When I submit the form, I have the last entity duplicated. This is not what I want!

The problem only occurs when I delete the first location, so only when there is an "index gap".

How can I avoid this? Is there an option?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

In thr PRE_BIND event I do this:

```
$data["locations"] = array_values($data["locations"]);
```

This removes the gaps from the array